# Can not query to AWS athena from Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory, amazon-athena, pyathena

I want to execute a query to AWS `athena` by `pyathena` on `Google` `Colaboratory`.
But `NoCredentialsError` will occur.

> NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

As running the same code in `sagemaker` will succeed, I think the code and user permissions has no problem.
Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Did you init your pyathena client with `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key ` ?

Comment: I used to write connect function's argument as 'access_key'.
'access_key'  is an argument of pyathenaJDBC.
After changing the argument to 'aws_access_key_id', I fixed it.
I'm sorry it's my misunderstanding and thanks for reply.  @ChouW

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed the problem : >